# Can't import sql dump file from the live site (trying to create a development site)

Tags: database

I am trying to create a development site which I can work on. So far, I have done:

1. creating a backup.sql using **drush sql-dump > backup.sql**
2. coping and pasting the live site folder for the development site folder
3. in the new project folder (dev site one) I copied, I changed the db name,username, and password, then tried to import the database dump file by **drush sql-query --file=backup.sql**

From step 3, after running the command, I am getting **[error] File(s) not found: backup.sql** ,
even after trying to clear the cache by **drush cr**, I get **SQLSATE[HY000] [1045] ACCESS DENIED FOR user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

It's really frustrating me because I have been trying to debug this for all day today. Would anyone be able to help me? I even changed the permission of the backup.sql and still cannot figure out why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That error almost always means your connection information for your database is incorrect. check the database username, password, and database name in settings.php.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did change the name of the db, username, and password for the development site folder. Is it why? I followed the tutorial and that's what they did?